# Sorting views in a grid after a view is moved via gesture to a new position

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, grid-layout

This is turing into a bit of a brain buster, but I assume there is a very simple and efficient method to do this.

In my app I have views laid out in a grid. Views can be moved to any location via gesture. The problem is making the view sort to just the right location after the gesture event. Basically I am doing this. Works sort of but not correct yet.

**Note**: the tag of the views will always update to the current position of the view in the grid.

Below is the code I am using to sort, and here is [a link to the actual project in a zip file](http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/SortableViews.zip).

```
-(void)sortViews:(UIView*)myView {

    __block int newIndex;

    // myView is the view that was moved.
    [viewsArray removeObject:myView];

    [viewsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){

        if (myView.center.x > view.center.x) {
            if (myView.center.y > view.center.y) {
                newIndex = view.tag -1;
                *stop = YES;
            } else {
                newIndex = view.tag +1;
                *stop = YES;
            }
        } else if (myView.center.x < view.center.x) {
            if (myView.center.y > view.center.y) {
                newIndex = view.tag -1;
                *stop = YES;
            } else {
                newIndex = view.tag +1;
                *stop = YES;
            }
        }

    }];

    if (newIndex < 0) {
        newIndex = 0;
    } else if (newIndex > 5) {
        newIndex = 5;
    }

    [viewsArray insertObject:myView atIndex:newIndex];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
        [self arrangeGrid];
    }];

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easier solution that seems to work just fine. I replace the code within the viewsArray enumeration with this:

```
   if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, myView.center)) {

        newIndex = view.tag;

         *stop = YES;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the original positions of all the views in an array (lets say `positionArray`), and then when you are moving a **view "A"** just go on checking the current position of **view "A"** with the stored positions in the `positionArray`, if a view is in range of any stored location just swap the position of **view "A"** with the view in whose range **view "A"** has come.

**Hope this will help you**